# How to change the data from column to row in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, unpivot

I need to transpose below column data into row data via SSIS dataflow

```
PP001   ADO002  ASN003  NIC001  NX002   HNL004  ABC001  TTD004
5   13  5   8   492 2   1   5
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your data flow has the Unpivot transformation on it which is the correct transformation to apply. Are you asking how to use it?

Comment: Yes, it is not working as expected

Comment: How is it working? How do you have it configured? What results is it producing?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty straight forward.

[image: overall]

All you have to do is add all columns to the Unpivot and you are done.

[image: Unpivot]

Comment: I saw the correct data into data view but not into destination csv file.

Comment: @ KeithL  - Attached screenshot above